# Pegas várias linhas de uma tabela no banco de dados com o mesmo nome e exibir o nome só uma vez em uma lista

Tags: php, html, sql, array

Meu formulário tem a opção de adicionar mais linhas, assim tive que usar array e enviar as informações dele para o banco de dados. Nesse caso no banco de dados se criou 3 linhas dentro da tabela com diversas informações, porém o nome(coluna em específico) tem a mesma informação nas três, e na hora de chamar para o html eu gostaria de chamar apenas uma vez esse nome que se repete 3 vezes.

conexão com db:

```
<?php
require_once('db_connect.php');

for( $i=0; $i<count($_POST['exercicio']); $i++ ) {     

    // INSERINDO NO MYSQL
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ficha  
                (nomeFicha,
                nomeExercicio,
                grupoMuscular, 
                numSeries,
                numRepeticoes,
                peso   
                ) 
            VALUES 
                (
                '".$_POST['nomeFicha']."',
                '".$_POST['exercicio'][$i]."',             
                '".$_POST['grupoMusc'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['numSeries'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['numRep'][$i]."',
                '".$_POST['peso'][$i]."'  
                )";

                echo $sql;

$queryExec = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die('ERRO ao inserir registro no Banco');
}

    if ( $queryExec) {
        header('location: ../fichas.php?sucesso');     
    } else {        
        header('location: ../fichas.php?erro'); 
    }
```

html:

```
 <div id="divContent" class="container-fluid">
          <ul id="lista" class="list-group">
            <?php
              $sql ="SELECT nomeFicha FROM ficha";
              $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
              while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)):
            ?>

              <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $dados['nomeFicha']; ?></li>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a instrução **DISTINCT** para retornar apenas os elementos diferentes na sua tabela.
Sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT nomeFicha FROM ficha;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp tem mais informações sobre isso.

Comment: Eu ja tinha conseguido achar a resposta mas vlw era isso msm que eu queria. Vou olhar o link que tu mandou.

Comment: @LucasKohler cuidado com essa referência. O w3schools não é de fiar.